# Charles Proxy Request and Response UnReadable with successful request

Tags: android, encoding, charles-proxy

Recently, I've been trying to intercept requests made by a specific app, and I have been successful in capturing these requests. However, I encounter difficulties when the "content-encoding" is set to "gzip" because the response body becomes unreadable. I need a solution to view the actual text within the response.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why Charles does not decompress it (may be because you are on the `Raw` tab?). In the end this is more a  question for Charles support than for Stackoverflow.